# memcached php module not compiling on EC2

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, memcached

I'm trying to do this on EC2, micro instance using amazon linux

I installed and started the memcached service without problems. But when trying to make the php part using pecl it told me pecl wasnt installed. So I installed pear, then pecl, when trying to run pecl install memcache I got an error asking for zlib (which btw, is installed), so instead I did this:

```
wget http://pecl.php.net/get/memcache-2.2.5.tgz
tar xvf memcache-2.2.5.tgz
cd memcache-2.2.5
phpize
./configure --with-zlib-dir=/usr/share/syslinux/com32/
```

But when I do the "make", I get a long list of errors, all of them in "zend" files, mostly missing types (ie. uint, hash_func_t, etc.).

My guess is that something else needs to be installed (ie. an include file with all the types that is asking for) , so I dont have to define all the missing types myself

```
In file included from /usr/include/php/Zend/zend.h:237,
                 from /usr/include/php/main/php.h:35,
                 from /usr/local/src/memcache-2.2.5/memcache.c:26:
/usr/include/php/Zend/zend_alloc.h:49: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'uint'
In file included from /usr/include/php/Zend/zend.h:270,
                 from /usr/include/php/main/php.h:35,
                 from /usr/local/src/memcache-2.2.5/memcache.c:26:
/usr/include/php/Zend/zend_hash.h:45: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before '*' token
/usr/include/php/Zend/zend_hash.h:45: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before 'uint'
/usr/include/php/Zend/zend_hash.h:45: error: 'ulong' declared as function returning a function
/usr/include/php/Zend/zend_hash.h:55: error: field 'h' declared as a function
/usr/include/php/Zend/zend_hash.h:56: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'uint'
/usr/include/php/Zend/zend_hash.h:67: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'uint'
/usr/include/php/Zend/zend_hash.h:87: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'uint'
/usr/include/php/Zend/zend_hash.h:99: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before 'uint'
/usr/include/php/Zend/zend_hash.h:99: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before 'hash_func_t'
In file included from /usr/include/php/Zend/zend.h:270,
                 from /usr/include/php/main/php.h:35,
                 from /usr/local/src/memcache-2.2.5/memcache.c:26:
/usr/include/php/Zend/zend_hash.h:100: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before 'uint'
/usr/include/php/Zend/zend_hash.h:100: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before 'hash_func_t'
```

etc... (list of errors is long...)

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with EC2, much more with the operating system you have installed on it. Please a) remove any mentions of EC2 b) specify your OS.

Comment: The OS is already specified: amazon linux. 
Amazon Linux AMI release 2011.02.1.1 (beta)
Kernel \r on an \m . I mention EC2 because that might ring a bell on someone that already had the same problem when trying to do this on it.

Comment: Learn this: you are running CentOS. Who cares about what a shady bookseller calls its own thrown together image? http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/index.html?LinuxAMIUserGuide.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about simply installing `php-pecl-memcache` instead of compiling one ?

Comment: memcache service is already installed and working, anso php and pecl. What I'm having trouble with is the php module for it

Comment: `php-pecl-memcache` is memcache client module for php, not memcached, and it's the package you're trying to compile

Comment: I tried yum install php-pecl-memcache and it worked with no errors, then added extension=memcache.so to php.ini, restarted apache, but php still not finding memcache functions

Comment: Wait, it worked! (I was testing the wrong server) Thanks! :)